# Regex doesn't ignore the optionnals groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying the create a regex to catch my url and his, optionnals, groups. The regex works fine if the url is complete. The optionnals groups are not optionnals at all.

Regex :

```
\/(.+)(?:\/(.+))(?:(?:\?(.+)))
```

Urls to catch :

- /taxi
- /taxi/lyon
- /taxi/lyon?coordinates=7542

https://regex101.com/r/NKFkwq/4/

As you can see, the third line is catched. But i'd like the first and second too.
I thought the **?:** will be enought to do that, but i missed something...

Thanks a lot for your help !
Cheers

**EDIT and answer**

Thanks in the comments for helping me. Here the great regex (the one i expected) : https://regex101.com/r/NKFkwq/8

Indeed **?:** is about ignoring a match, not made him optionnal.

Comment: `?:` does not make a group optional, it just makes it non-capturing. Use `?` _after_ the group to make it optional. Try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/NKFkwq/5)?

Comment: [Regex Isn't Broken](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) ;)

Comment: @L3viathan Ok interresting, i'm trying to update the regex with this new information, thanks !

Comment: @sp00m ahah sure i am broken, there is no doubt about it

Comment: @L3viathan your regex works perfectly ! https://regex101.com/r/NKFkwq/5 thanks a lot

Comment: Regex should not ignore non-capturing groups, it is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern consists of capturing and non capturing groups. The `(?:` denotes a non capturing group.

If you want to match all 3 lines, you could use match the part starting from the first forward slash and make the part starting from the second forward slash optional.

```
^/[^\s/]+(?:/[^\s/]+)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `/[^\s/]+` Match `/` and match 1+ times any char except a whitespace or `/`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `/[^\s/]+` Match `/` and match 1+ times any char except a whitespace or `/`
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M1e5Me/1)

---

If you want to have capturing groups, but don't want to match `/taxi?coordinates=7542` you could nest the groups and make them optional as well.

```
^/\w+(/\w+(\?\S*)?)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `/\w+` Match `/` and 1+ word chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `/\w+` Match `/` and 1+ word chars
  - `(` Capture **group 2**
  - `\?\S*` Match `?` and 0+ times a non whitespace char
  - `)?` Close group 2
- `)?` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8G0enQ/1)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Indeed i confused the ?: for the non capturing group and the ? after a group to made it optionnal. L3viathan answered me on the comment of the first post with a correct regex. Yours seems correct but didnt make groups as i expected. Check this one : https://regex101.com/r/NKFkwq/5

Anyway thanks for the details of your post, i'll work my regex skill !

Comment: @RenishV8 As a side note, if you don't want to match `/taxi?coordinates=7542` you could nest the capturing groups as well and make them optional `^/\w+(/\w+(\?.*)?)?$` https://regex101.com/r/yfHX32/1

Comment: Actually i want to match if it exists, the perfect regex to me (for now) is : https://regex101.com/r/NKFkwq/8. Everything matched as i wanted. Thanks for your precious informations